# The integral condition

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $X \subset Y$ be a subring of ring $Y$, and suppose that $Y$ is integral
>    over $X$. Show that $Y^* \cap X=X^*$. Can the integrality condition be omitted?

Let $x \in X^*$, since $X \subset Y$, $x \in Y^*$. Conversely, let $y \in Y^* \cap X$ and $y^{-1} \in Y$. Since $Y$ is integral over $X$, there exists $r_1,..,r_n \in X$ such that 
$$y^{-n}+ r_1y^{-n+1}+...+r_n=0$$
As $y \in X$, $y^{-1}=-(r_1+r_2y+..+r_ny^{n-1}) \in X$. Hence $Y^* \cap X=X^*$.

Could anyone indicate the counterexamples that integrality condition can not be omitted? Are there any examples in number ring?

Comment: Why not take a localization? Let $X\subset X_f$ where $f$ is a non-zero divisor which not a unit in $X$. Then $f\in X_f^*\cap X$, but $f\not\in X^*$.

Comment: First (non-number field) example that comes to my mind: Consider $X=R[x]\subseteq R[x,x^{-1}]=Y$ for a ring $R$ and a indeterminate $x$, then $x\in Y^\ast\cap X$ but $x$ is not invertible in $X$.

Comment: thank you mathmax and Mohan